# octobercms showing relationship data

Tags: octobercms

I am new to octobercms. I am facing problem in showing the relationship data on my twig template page.

On my page I am fetching records like:

```
$this['education'] = Education::where('user_id', '=', $logged_in_user->id)->with('transcript')->get();
```

on my partials I am able to get the records like:

```
[  
  {  
    "id":56,
    "user_id":6,
    "created_at":"2017-08-24 07:56:09",
    "updated_at":"2017-08-25 16:39:17",
    "school_name":"UCT",
    "degree_name":"Finance",
    "majors":"test2",
    "achievements":"",
    "transcript":{  
      "id":20,
      "disk_name":"59a03695e24c3772338596.png",
      "file_name":"step1.png",
      "file_size":68042,
      "content_type":"image\/png",
      "title":null,
      "description":null,
      "field":"transcript",
      "sort_order":20,
      "created_at":"2017-08-25 16:39:17",
      "updated_at":"2017-08-25 16:39:17",
      "path":"http:\/\/talentlatch.dev\/storage\/app\/uploads\/public\/59a\/036\/95e\/59a03695e24c3772338596.png",
      "extension":"png"
    },
    "start_date":"2015-01-01 00:00:00",
    "end_date":"2017-08-01 00:00:00",
    "is_fulltime":1
  }
]
```

but when I am trying to show file name attribute on page, I am unable to get it. I have tried below solutions:

```
{{ education[0].transcript.file_name }}
```

and

```
{{ education[0]['transcript'].file_name }}
```

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: did you tried a foreach like
 `{% foreach item in education %}
item.transcript.filename {% endfor %}
`

Answer (score 0):

Education variable is Collection, so try

`{{ education.first().id }}`

If you will be successful, then try

`{{ education.first().transcript.file_name }}`